# FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger

Tags: android, exception, pid

can someone help me to fix these errors. I added my app to the firebase and did test run. and I got these errors. I am new to android app development. I have no clear idea where should I start to fix these errors.

```html
 Fatal exception
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/QR%20and%20Barcode/text.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: one.teqtoapps.barqr, PID: 9659
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/QR%20and%20Barcode/text.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
 at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1958)
 at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2348)
 at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:941)
 at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9735)
 at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9741)
 at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9720)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1609)
 at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.execStartActivity(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:152)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
 at one.teqtoapps.barqr.utility.AppUtils.share(AppUtils.java:83)
 at one.teqtoapps.barqr.fragment.GenerateFragment$6.onSaved(GenerateFragment.java:183)
 at one.teqtoapps.barqr.utility.SaveImage.onPostExecute(SaveImage.java:41)
 at one.teqtoapps.barqr.utility.SaveImage.onPostExecute(SaveImage.java:16)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
 at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
 at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:142)
 at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:96)
 at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:37)
 at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:74)
 at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:52)
 at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:9)
 at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.a(Tap.java:19)
 at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.b(Tap.java:2)
 at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:22)
 at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
 at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:78)
 at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:94)
 at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Crashes on some devices during Google Play test
I thought this will help you :
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113164874

In my case, it show in log

> Failed to take screenshot: takeScreenshot returned null
>
> copied 4 bytes
>
> 01-29 06:27:43.544: I/Robo(11035): --------- beginning of crash
>
> 01-29 06:27:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(11035): FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
>
> 01-29 06:27:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(11035): Process:  PID: 11035
>
> 01-29 06:27:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(11035): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.recycle()' on a null object reference

because my screen has secure flag to take screen-shot and testing framework trying to take screen-shot that will return null and throwing NullPointerException on recycle.

For more help you can reply me here.